# Vue selectize, getting json data from option?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, selectize.js

I'm using [vue2-selectize](https://github.com/rhyek/vue2-selectize) to display list of options fetched from axios call:

```
<template>
    <selectize v-model="selected" :settings="settings">
        <option v-for="option in options" :value="option.id">
            ({{ option.author }}) - {{ option.description }}
        </option>
    </selectize>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['old-value'],

        data() {
            return {
                selected: this.oldValue,
                options: [],
                settings: {
                    preload: true,
                    placeholder: "Search All Authors",
                    dropdownParent: 'body',
                    closeOnSelect: true,

                    render: {
                        option: function (data) {
                            console.log(data);
                            return '<div>' +
                                data.displayName +
                                '<div class="item-bio">' +
                                data.bio +
                                '</div>';
                        }
                    },

                    load: async (query, callback) => {
                        axios.get(route('api.showAllAuthors')).then(response => {
                            this.options = response.data;
                            callback();
                        })
                    }
                },
            }
        },
    }
</script>
```

The issue is that once you setup the `<option>` for the select you can only work with the two values it passes to the render function (`text` and `value`) and not the original object (whereas the actual `<option>` has access to this object).

The manual mentions the optional parameter of `dataAttr` available for `<option>` tags, but setting `<option :data-data="option">` has no effect and I still can't access the original properties.

How can I access the original JSON attributes that the `<option>` is using in the render function?

Answer (score 0):

```
var value = selectizeObject.getValue(),
    optionJson = selectizeObject.options[value];
```

selectizeObject is object for given select / input. For example with jQuery:

```
var selectizeObject = $('#my-select')[0].selectize;
```